# Cron does not execute the nodejs script

Tags: node.js, cron

I want to run my script through cron. But when I try to execute it the script does not start. What am I doing wrong?

**sudo crontab -e:**

```
5 * * * * /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node /home/admin/project/index.js
```

**index.js:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

...
var fs = require('fs');

function formatDate(date) {
    var monthNames = [
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October",
        "November", "December"
    ];
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    return day + '_' + monthNames[monthIndex] + '_' + year;
}

function formatTime(time) {
    var hours = time.getHours();
    var minutes = time.getMinutes();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds();
    return hours + '_' + minutes + '_' + seconds;
}

var ws = fs.createWriteStream(`./log/test-${formatDate(new Date())}-${formatTime(new Date())}.log`, {
    'flags': 'w',
    'encoding': 'utf8'
});

process.stdout.wr = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.er = process.stderr.write;

process.stdout.write = function (mes, c) {
    ws.write(mes + '\r\n');
    process.stdout.wr(mes, c);
};

process.stderr.write = function (mes, c) {
    ws.write(mes + '\r\n');
    process.stdout.er(mes, c);
};
...
```

**grep CRON /var/log/syslog:**

```
Jun 17 09:05:01 admin-serv CRON[861]: (admin) CMD (/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node /home/admin/project/index.js)
```

**ps aux | grep index.js**

```
admin 921 0.0 0.0 21320 1016 pts/0 S+ 09:05 0:00 grep --color=auto index.js
```

Naturally, when I run this command

```
/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node /home/admin/project/index.js
```

through the terminal, everything works.

Comment: I notice you don't specify which user is supposed to run the command?
https://linuxconfig.org/linux-crontab-reference-guide

Comment: @OddmarDam Running as administrator and editing the file also does not help.

Comment: Is the file executable for the user running it ?

Comment: @OddmarDam ls -l `-rwxrwxr-x 1 admin admin 3114 jun 17 08:43 index.js`

Comment: An unrelated question, but why do you have `bash` shebang on a node script? Shouldn't it be `#!/usr/bin/env node`?

Comment: @Zlatko I have corrected

Answer (score 0):

process.stdout doesn't work when you execute the script from cron. You'll want to use console.log instead if you're intending to run the script without a terminal.