# Why is cron not executing my node.js script properly?

Tags: node.js, cron

I am trying to run a node.js script from cron. It is supposed to read a .json-File, make an API call and then write the response to a .json-File.

When executing manually everything works fine.

**This does it's job**

```
sudo node ~/bots/gtaa/index.js
```

**sudo crontab -e**

```
29 9 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/node ~/bots/gtaa/index.js >> ~/gtaa-bot.log 2>&1
```

**grep cron /var/log/syslog**

```
May 11 09:29:01 raspberrypi CRON[54381]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/node ~/bots/gtaa/index.js >> ~/gtaa-bot.log 2>&1)
```

**My index.js uses the local .env-File**

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' })
```

There also is **no** `gtaa-bot.log`-File in the home directory.

A very similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624617/cron-does-not-execute-the-nodejs-script) but there are no useful answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have experienced this issue, more recently using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Ultimately what ends up happening is cron runs in a different environment and most likely is unable to find the correct path to node.

There are some ways to configure this, however I found a much easier solution ended up being to just have cron execute a bash script, that runs nvm and/or node.

For example, I have this setup to run every 20 minutes:

```
20 * * * * /bin/bash/ /home/user/nvm_cron.sh
```

And in my `nvm_cron.sh` file:

```
# Load nvm
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
nvm use 16.14.0

# Run node program
cd /home/user/folder && node start.js
```

*Dont forget to make sure the `nvm_cron.sh` file is executable*

This way I have control over the version of node that I want to run for the script, and don't have to worry about messing with cron.

Comment: Ty that worked ! even when I was calling node from nvm directly from crontab it doesn't work